# Show that if H is hermitian, then <Ψ|H|Φ> = <HΨ|Φ>

Tags: quantum-chemistry

Since H is hermitian, it is equal to its complex conjugate (shown below), a property which I used to do the proof:

[image: it]

I had to prove that <Ψ|H|Φ> = <HΨ|Φ>, which I did as below:

[image]

My question is whether my proof is valid - are the two things equal because the pink bits equal each other?

Comment: There are several mistakes. Let's begin with your first line. The second equality is wrong (as per your "definition", you need to take the complex conjugate of the entire integral). On the second line, the second equality is wrong. You've taken the conjugate of the integrand. If you do that, you will get the conjugate of the result. Again, the entire integral needs a conjugate to make that correct.

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts. (You have been already informed about this once.)

Answer (score 1):

As the operator $H$ is linear, when taking it out of the bra symbol it must be replaced by its adjoint and placed on the right, i.e. $\langle H\psi|=\langle \psi|H^\dagger$ and so $\langle  H^\dagger\psi|=\langle \psi|(H^\dagger)^\dagger=\langle\psi| H$. In you case the operator is hermitian so  $H=H^\dagger$. Compare with $|H\psi\rangle$ which is another way of designating the ket $H|\psi\rangle$.